# Git lost changes I had made to a file

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I had a class with a function, like so:

Revision 1:

`Foo.cs`:

```cs
class Foo
{
    void DoSomething();
}
```

Which I committed.

I then added a new inherited class which needed to override class `Foo` so I changed it up a bit:

Revision 2:

`Foo.cs`:

```cs
class Foo
{
    protected virtual void DoSomething();
}
```

`FooToo.cs`:

```cs
class FooToo : Foo
{
    protected override void DoSomething();
}
```

Today, all of a sudden out of no where it appears that `Foo.cs` has reverted to Revision 1 therefore my code is no longer compiling (as `FooToo.cs` still exists).

The part that really blows my mind is when I show log on `Foo.cs` **there is no revision 2 commit in the log.**

So I think clearly somewhere I have messed up big time.

I gave `FooToo.cs` a look and in the commit file list there was `Foo.cs` with the changes from Revision 2!

This has affected various aspects of my project on multiple levels and source files, fixing it is not going to be easy or straightforward if I do it manually file by file.

So my question is, what did Git do to my files and how do I fix this disaster?

Update:

I decided to export Revision 2 that I could see from `FooToo.cs`' log file to a zip file. After I did this somehow Git started showing the correct log for `Foo.cs`.

I do not understand what happened or how this managed to sort itself out, does anyone have any idea?

**I fully appreciate that I must sound like a mad man but this is what I saw happen.**

Comment: So wait, you have no commit in the log but you are looking at the second file and seeing the commit for the first file? Files don't store information about other file commits, only commits do - are you sure you aren't just looking at another branch or have forgotten to push the commit?

Comment: Make sure you opened the log on the root of your working tree. If you used `reset`by mistake, you can look up the reflog which contains a log of all changes to references (such as HEAD or your branch).

Comment: So if I show log on Foo.cs I do not see any changes past the initial commit. On FooToo.cs I see a change aade to Foo.cs after the initial commit.

I was not looking at another branch, itw as definitely the same branch (I suspected the same thing), I checked the repo url and looked int he repro browser just to be certain.

Comment: Could you post `git status`, `git branch branch -av` and `git remote show origin` to understand what happend (hopefully)?